# Website doesn't load at all - how to debug?

Tags: php

After making few edits in PHP code, I refreshed my web app and it didn't load at all - only white screen. Nothing in console. In such case it's very difficult to investigate what could be the problem because I can't even get any errors. Perhaps there is a way to show them? Like modyfying Apache configuration or some tools?

I remember which lines I've modified before the "white-screen", but instead of guessing why they are incorrect I'd like to know how to get errors from the browser.

Comment: "In such case it's very difficult to investigate what could be the problem because I can't even get any errors." Enabling error reporting is not really that hard.

Comment: http://www.dzone.com/snippets/let-php-show-all-errors

Comment: check your apache error logs first

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info Under "I have a typical "does not work" problem. What should I do before asking a question?"

Comment: it might be logic error not syntax error

Comment: ok, all I needed to know was in php_error_log